# Touch Target Size too small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am currently facing an issue where Android Studio is suggesting to increase the touch target size for a button due to it being too small. Most recommendations online suggest setting **minHeight** to "48dp," but doing so **affects the visual design of my layout**.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/Dinning"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selected_button_color"
            android:minHeight="34dp"
            android:text="Dinning"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selected_text_color"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
```

I want to maintain the visual height of the button at 34dp as per my UI design, but I also need to address the "Touch Target Size too small" warning. Increasing minHeight to 48dp is not an option for me.

Is there a way to resolve this warning without compromising the visual design by keeping the minHeight at 34dp? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Update**:
I changed AppCompatButton to TextView, warning is gone.

Comment: I had the same problem. I ignored the warning and had never problems all over the years ...

Comment: yeah i cant see another option now. :(

Answer (score 1):

As it's warning you can ignore it but if you want to improve it you can follow this solution which will not affect your UI and also removed this warning.

If you set `setOnClickListener` on this button it'll be hard to click sometime because touch area is too small and may `setOnClickListener` not trigger.

To solve this you can set `48dp` for size and set padding. like if you use any image drawable then set padding to main image so your UI will not messed up and you can get rid of *Touch Target Size too small* warning

> With `Button` we use `android:background` so padding not work here but you can use this solution for `ImageView`, `TextView` and other views. Might it help for other clickable views in your project.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:padding="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />
```

[image: with padding]

and If I remove padding it shows

[image: without padding]

So, You can maintain UI and Touch area as well.